# Content approval by roles workflow

Tags: workflows

So I am looking at creating a website in Drupal (In the past I have used PHP and in the past few years, Symfony), however, I can not work out the workflows when it comes to approval for content.

The way the organisation will work is there will be a large number of people that will need to be able to create and edit content pages, but should not be able to publish them. Then one of the admins will look at the page and fix up any code required and make the page a bit neater, and then publish.

The first thing is, I need to know how to make a role where the user can add (not sure if adding will be required yet) and edit a page, but not publish it.

The second thing is when a page is edited and the checkbox for publishing is not selected, it unpublishes the page! That really should not be the case, it should just stay at the current revision and the saved page should just be a newer revision awaiting publishing.

I am running tests on the opensourcecms servers at the moment (with their 24hr testing system), so can not upload my own modules to the server.

Comment: please have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation this should get you where you need to https://youtu.be/j6lnisX9bUg?t=227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your use can you should use [workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) 
with [workbench_moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation)

> Workbench Moderation adds arbitrary moderation states to Drupal core's "unpublished" and "published" node states, and affects the behavior of node revisions when nodes are published. Moderation states are tracked per-revision; rather than moderating nodes, Workbench Moderation moderates revisions.

Comment: OK, that looks interesting, I don't suppose you know if there is any way of testing a module in a demo environment (like openourcecms)? I just want to have a bit of a play before I set up an environment on my own servers.

Comment: you can test this modules here https://simplytest.me/

Comment: Seems there is an issue with this site. Every time I try, I get "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." There is a notification to say there is an issue with spawning some distributions, but I didn't find any that worked. Will keep an eye on the site and see if they get it fixed.

Comment: OK, seems simplytest.me is working now. I am looking at the content moderation, but the issue is that when the editor edits the content, it goes from published to needs review, so disappears off the website. Shouldn't the currently published version stay as published and a new revision have the status of needs review?

Comment: Go to content type settings and set the default to published

Comment: That means that someone without publish permissions can not do an edit to send into needs review (I need the previous version to stay as published and the new version to go as needs review)

Comment: OK, so setting the default to draft made it work now, not sure why (same settings I had before). But now there is no option of making edits go directly to needs review (the default is set to needs review and the workflow is there). I was also wondering where I can see a list of items that have a status of needs review? Would be handy to see a list rather than have editors tell me every page that I need to publish!