# Where are the "My Drafts" and "Needs Reviews" tabs?

Tags: workbench

I am experimenting in simplytest.me to see if Drupal will suit our needs. I have been testing the workbench moderation module to get the work flow that will be required (content editors and then approval before publishing). I am running the default version of Drupal there (8.x-1.5) and want to see any items that are in draft or needs approval status. I am seeing reference to tabs that show me just that, however, I can not find the tabs anywhere. Is this something that has changed in the latest version or have I not ticked something or am I looking in the wrong place (was looking under "content" page)?

Comment: Isn’t the core content moderation and workflow advised over this now?

Comment: This is the suggestion I got at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277938/content-approval-by-roles-workflow/277940?noredirect=1#comment345344_277940 If there is a better way to do this, could you please leave an answer there so I can try it out? Thanks